# logstash sincedb_path is not working

Tags: logstash

This is not working. There is no output. I want to use sincedb_path => "/mnt/elk/logstash/scripts/sincedb/from_nifi_dev_logs_nifi_6

```
sudo rm -rf /mnt/elk/logstash/scripts/sincedb/from_nifi_dev_logs_nifi_6

sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input { file { path => "/mnt/elk/logstash/data/from/nifi/dev/logs/nifi_copied/nifi-app.log"  sincedb_path => "/mnt/elk/logstash/scripts/sincedb/from_nifi_dev_logs_nifi_6" } } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }' --verbose
```

There are no sincedb files in default directory.

```
ls /usr/share/logstash/data/plugins/inputs/file
no files
```

This is working. I don't want to use start_position => beginning sincedb_path => "/dev/null"

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input { file { path => "/mnt/elk/logstash/data/from/nifi/dev/logs/nifi_copied/nifi-app.log"  start_position => beginning sincedb_path => "/dev/null" } } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }' --verbose  
{
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "hostname",
          "path" => "/mnt/elk/logstash/data/from/nifi/dev/logs/nifi_copied/nifi-app.log",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-02-07T19:24:31.758Z,
       "message" => "Caused by: java.io.IOException: null"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add **start_position => beginning** to your command.

From [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-start_position)

> **start_position:** The default behavior treats files like live streams and thus starts at the end. If you have old data you want to import, set this to beginning.

Run this command:

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input { file { path => "/mnt/elk/logstash/data/from/nifi/dev/logs/nifi_copied/nifi-app.log" start_position => beginning sincedb_path => "/mnt/elk/logstash/scripts/sincedb/from_nifi_dev_logs_nifi_6" } } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }' --verbose
```

Also, ensure **from_nifi_dev_logs_nifi_6** is a file and not a directory.

From [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path)

> **sincedb_path:** Path of the sincedb database file... NOTE: it must be a file path and not a directory path